# View all keys for plone catalog result

Tags: plone, catalog

How to show all keys for items that I get in a catalog search?

```
links = self.catalog(portal_path='Link')
for link in links:
    for value in link:
        print value
```

With this code I can show all values, but I don't know how to show the keys.

Comment: There are no keys; what values do you expect? You are looping over `links` twice there.

Comment: I was trying to get remoteUrl for links. But I couldn't do this without the key.

Comment: It were `for value in link` instead of `for value in links`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ZCatalog does not return dictionaries. It returns a sequence of result objects (called Catalog Brains, because you can give them smarts. Long historical story).

So you loop over them, and each object has attributes for each metadata column you defined in the catalog:

```
links = self.catalog(portal_path='Link')
for link in links:
    print link.Title
```

If you need to dynamically loop over the available attributes, use `.schema()` for the keys:

```
for link in links:
    for key in link.schema():
        print link[attr]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

`for link in links:
    link.schema()`